# Xcode 7.3 and Xamarin Studio 5 event handler creation

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.mac

Could anyone tell me or point to a guide explaining how to create event handlers for Xamarin.Mac forms?

I simply cannot find how to do it when I open XCode Interface Editor from Xamarin Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for what is called an `Action` in Cocoa.

There is a great tech article that takes you through the process of exposing an `Action` (and `Outlets`) in the Xcode Interface Editor so the 'event' is exposed via auto-generated (code-behind) C#:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/user-interface/standard-controls/

### A Simple example:

Create a Cocoa App via the Xamarin Studio template.

**Double-click the `Main.Storyboard` entry in the solution explorer to open Xcode**

Drag/Drop an NSButton onto your `View` (not the `View Controller`):

[image]

Highlight the `NSButton` and Ctrl-Drag/Drop it onto the ViewController.h (NOT the `.m` file):

[image]

Name it (`MyButton` for my example) and change the Connection from `Outlet` to `Action`.

Save the storyboard (Cmd-S) and flip back to Xamarin Studio (no need to close Xcode as you will be flipping back and forth a lot as you initially get up to speed.

In Xamarin, double click on the generated file `ViewController.designer.cs` and you will see your NSButton's partial class.

```
    [Action ("MyButton:")]
    partial void MyButton (Foundation.NSObject sender);
```

Double-click on the `ViewController.cs` file, click within the class but outside of other existing methods and start typing `partial` and you will get an Intellisense popup listing your Actions:

[image]

Hit enter and you have your first event created.

```
    partial void MyButton (NSObject sender)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException ();
    }
```

Update the code to actually do something:

```
    partial void MyButton (NSObject sender)
    {
        (sender as NSButton).Title = "You clicked me";
    }
```

Compile/Run the app:

[image]

Click the button:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For a deeper understanding of Outlets and Actions, please see the [Outlet and Action](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/getting_started/hello,_mac/#Outlets_and_Actions) section of our [Hello, Mac](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/getting_started/hello,_mac) guide as well. I go into a bit more details of how they work in that doc.